# Customize Dataform run calls with variables

Tags: dataform

Is it possible to tell dataform to run a flow (the SQL query) with custom parameters provided by me? Something like: `curl my_flow --start_date=20220101 --end_date=20220801` and this vars will be used inside my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a response from Liam Binns-Conroy (the Dataform slack community). Thanks to him.

> You can use custom variables to specify params in the dataform.json
> file, and then pass values in using the dataform CLI vars flag. You
> then reference the values in the sqlx file like this
> `dataform.projectConfig.vars.myVariableName`

Answer (score 0):

from: https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/reuse-code-includes

```
// filename is includes/constants.js
  const PROJECT_ID = "my_project_name";
  module.exports = { PROJECT_ID };
```

The following code sample references the PROJECT_ID constant in a table definition query in a SQLX file:

```
  config { type: "table" }
  SELECT * FROM ${constants.PROJECT_ID}.my_schema_name.my_table_name
```